# Definition of Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that  an abelian group is a set G, with a binary operation $$ + : G \times G \rightarrow G  \\ (a,b) \mapsto+(a,b)=: a+b$$ such that for every $a,b,c \in G$

i) $\exists 0 \in G $ such that $ a+0 =  a$

ii) $\exists a'$ such that $a + a' = 0$

iii)  $a + (b + c) = (a +b) + c$

iv) $a+b = b+a$

Now, I need a little help with the concept of subgroup. Intuitively I think of that as a subset of a group that is also a group. So because we select elements from a group G, iii) and iv) are automatically satisfied. With that idea I would define a subgroup as:

A subgroup of a group $G$ is a subset $G_0$ such that for every $a \in G_0$ :

i) $\exists 0 \in G_0 $ such that $ a+0 =  a$

ii) $\exists a'$ such that $a + a' = 0$

But instead I have the following definition

An abelian group, $ A_0 \subseteq A$ it said to be an abelian subgroup if

i) $0 \in A_0$

ii) $\forall a,b \in A_0 \ a-b \in A_0$

Are those equivalent? or there is something that I am missing?

Comment: Regarding subgroup criterion, see [my answer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157669/group-proof-disproof/3157681#3157681), though there the group is written multiplicatively (not necessarily Abelian)

Comment: I suppose $A$ must be an abelian group? (The grammar seems confusing to me.)

Answer (score 2):

Your definition would allow $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ to be a subgroup of the integers under addition. It's not since it doesn't contain $1+1$.

Answer (score 0):

An abelian subgroup satisfies $a+b=b+a$ rather than $a-b \in A_0$. Any non-empty subset of a group $A_0$ satisfying $a-b \in A_0$ is in fact a subgroup and this property is called the subgroup criterion. It doesn't not force the subgroup to be abelian.